# Need jQuery show/hide advice, to show specific div depending on previous page click

Tags: jquery, hide, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, show

I've built a page that has a side navigation, where each option clicked causes a certain DIV to show and the others to be hidden. I've written the jQuery for this and it works like a charm.

What I'm stumped with is whether or not it's possible have links on other pages actually link to different sections on this page. In other words, a link for "Section One" that opens this page with Section One showing, and a link for "Section Two" that opens this page with Section Two already showing.

Can anyone help?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #content div.section    {   display:none;   }
    #content div.one    {   display:block;  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#side_nav ul li a').click(function() {
        $('#side_nav ul li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).attr('class');

            $('#content div.section').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<section class="main wrapper">
    <div id=side_nav>       
        <ul>
            <li class=current><a href="#" class=one>TOPIC ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=two>TOPIC TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=three>TOPIC THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id=content>
        <div class="section one">
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>One Content</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>One Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section two">
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>Two Content</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>Two Content</p>
        </div>                                      
        <div class="section three">
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>Three Content</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
            <p>Three Content</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

Could anyone detail how I would use 'window.location.hash' to capture the hash tag from the incoming link click, and pass it through the Javascript above in order to display the appropriate div?

Comment: This is what anchors are for.

Comment: try to disable default action with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the links from other pages include some extra information then when your page loads you will be able to detect which section you should be displaying.

You could provide the link class value as a hash value on the incoming links such as `yourpage.html#one` then use `window.location.hash` to retrieve the value.

In your case you could then add some code to your `document.ready()` handler to see if the incoming link has a value and display the section as appropriate.

EDIT:
Update to include example of implementation.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var hashFromLink = window.location.hash != '' ? window.location.hash.replace('#','') : "";
        loadSection(hashFromlink);

        $('#side_nav ul li a').click(function() {
            $('#side_nav ul li.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current');

            var filterVal = $(this).attr('class');

            $('#content div.section').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function loadSection(filterVal) {
        $('#content div.section.' + filterVal).fadeIn(200);                // this should fade in the section with the location hash class
        $('#side_nav ul li a.' + filterVal).parent().addClass('current');  // this should find the anchor tag in the nav and apply the current class to its parent
    }
</script>
```

Just a couple more notes, obviously this is just one way you could do it. I think these selectors should work and you also might want to sanitize the input from the hash value.

Comment: would you be so kind as to give me an example of what the document.ready() code would look like using the window.location.hash script? I've only added in the external http://mysite.html#one link on the other page so far. Thanks!

Comment: @glenn I have updated my answer to include and example implementation.

Comment: you got me on the right track and works beautifully now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a hash to your document url to identify which section should be expanded.

```
http://www.mysite.com/#two
```

Then check via javascript and expand the appropriate area

```
var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');
if (hash != '') {
    $('a.' + hash).addClass('current');  //selector is equiv of $('a.two')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

building off of mrtshermans answer (which worked great for me...thanks!)...

if (hash == '') {

//do something if there if hash if empty or null

}

if(hash !=='' {

//do something if hash is set

$('a.' + hash).css('color', '#ffffff');

}

Note using '==' rather than '=' was needed to get some of my css to take effect.